# Pulsing and Constant light from 3-way switch?

Tags: electrical, lighting

We have two hallway lights controlled by two separate light switches (3 way switch). One switch has a dimmer, the other does not.

When we turn on the hallway light, with the dimmer at its lowest level, half the time both lights are on at the lowest levels of brightness (constant) and the other half of the time the lights transfer, turning on one at a time (pulsing). The probability that the light is either constant or pulsing is approximately random (50 percent)

Any idea as to why this effect is occurring?

Comment: There is a *possibility*, depending on the "smarts" involved, that the dimmer may need some power to remember the status when "off". If the wiring is panel->plain switch->dimmer->lights or panel->lights->switch 1->switch 2 then this could be the problem. If it is panel->dimmer->switch 2->lights then it is likely something else.

Comment: What make and model is the dimmer in question?  Also, what make and model are the lightbulbs?